# Cocoa NSOutlineView bug - [NSCFTimer copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: cocoa

I'm using an NSOutlineView with the function

```
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView
  isGroupItem:(id)item
```

defined so it gives the group row GUI look.  When I add a root item, it works fine.  When I add an item to root's child array and expand it, it works fine.  If I contract the item though, the following error is logged:

```
[NSCFTimer copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I also get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error if the app window is deactivated by switching to another app.  I used the debugger to try to find where I might have made an error in one of my functions, but the stack trace only shows functions I did not create (RunCurrentEventLoopInMode, CFRunLoopRunSpecific, handleWindowNeedsDisplay, etc.)  Does anyone have any idea where my error(s) might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like an object is dying prematurely. You get the “unrecognized selector sent to instance” exception when a new object is allocated later with the same pointer and then something tries to send the old object a message (in the example shown, the reincarnation is an NSTimer and the message something tried to send the previous object was `copyWithZone:`). You get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash when the object is simply garbage memory.

Debug this by running your app under Instruments with the Zombies instrument enabled. The object will, instead of dying, become a zombie object. When something tries to send a zombie a message, the zombie will moan (figuratively speaking), which will show up in Instruments's timeline as a flag. You can click a button in that flag to view the history of the object, including all of its retentions and releases.